# Distance Matrix of Shortest Paths from all m points to all n points through a network

Tags: qgis, network, distance-matrix

This question was asked many times and I could reference endless GIS-SE links here. Most of them suggest using pgRouting, which is not an option here. I have to use QGIS (for other technical questions). Others suggest QNEAT3 plugin, which is not working as expected (see [OD Matrix from Layers as Lines (m:n) always reports NULL #25](https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3/issues/25)).

So I'm looking for a definitive answer, which can be referenced forever here and put an end to new ones (and, of course, put an end to my recurrent problem). I know it is possible to have a purely QGIS-based answer, as pointed out in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html#finding-shortest-paths). With my somewhat superficial python knowledge, I can't do it myself, but I know it's possible.

**Problem**

I have three layers:

- `m` points in a map layer `origins`;
- `n` points in a map layer `destinations`;
- `k` arcs/paths/lines in a map layer `network`;

I need a distance matrix of shortest paths from all `m` points to all `n` points through that network.

**Almost a solution**

The [Shortest path (point to layer)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html?highlight=network#shortest-path-point-to-layer) tool is the closest solution you can readily have. Except by the fact you have to manually input the `from` coordinates picking it from the map. This can be really painful if you have 100+ `from` origins to calculate.

**Easiest solution I can foresee**

- use the [Shortest path (point to layer, dijkstra method) tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html) iterating through all records of the `origins` map layer getting its coordinates and processing it in a loop.

**Some test datasets**

https://github.com/jecogeo/network_analysis_test_dataset

The problem is how?

I'm relatively new to QGIS and I'm not sure how to build a model or modify the native tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**QNEAT3** is definitely the right choice for solving this task. As pointed out by you in the [QNEAT3 issue](https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3/issues/25) you achieve faulty outputs using the OD-Matrix algorithms. I tested the dataset comparing QNEAT3 results with the native QGIS routing algorithms (which QNEAT3 is basically built upon) and was able to detect a bug related to the `tolerance parameter` not being wired to the `QgsGraphBuilder`. I will post a patch for this problem during the next weeks - to solve the problem on the fly you can also update the source code of your installed QNEAT3 plugin.

The solution for on **QNEAT3 version 1.0.3** and should be fixed in future versions:

1. Navigate to the QNEAT3 folder in the QGIS plugins folder
2. Open the file `Qneat3Framework.py`
3. Go to line *121* and add `True, input_tolerance` in the constructor of `QgsGraphBuilder`
4. The line should now be

   `self.builder = QgsGraphBuilder(self.AnalysisCrs, True, input_tolerance)`
5. Save the file and open QGIS or reload QNEAT3 using the plugin reloader.
6. Test your analysis with the desired tolerance parameter.
7. Enjoy the fixed result

Thank you for reporting this bug - you just triggered the release of QNEAT3 version 1.0.4. :)